# How do I import a module from the same directory explicitly in Python 2?

Tags: python, import

I'm looking for a clarification of the following statement in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

> Implicit relative imports should *never* be used and have been removed in Python 3.

Suppose that in Python 2 I have the following directory structure (in a directory called `test`):

```
.
├── test_recurring_interval.py
└── test_utils.py
```

In the file `test_recurring_interval.py`, I have a line

`import test_utils`

Is this an implicit relative import? If so, how should I change it to make it explicit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether this is an implicit relative import depends on whether the module containing the import statement is part of a package. This is trickier than it might at first seem, since whether a module is part of a package depends on how Python was executed and how `__package__` and `sys.path` are set.

It doesn't look like there are any packages involved here. This is an absolute import, then, not a relative import.

Answer (score 1):

An explicit relative import is *explicitly relative* when it starts with a `.`.

**Implicitily relative:**

```
import test_utils
```

**Explicitily relative:**

```
import .test_utils
```